# R regex continuing past end of pattern

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to take certain sections out of a string using regex in R but its is taking out too much, continuing past the end of my pattern and I can not figure out why.

My goal is to take out a section of a string which starts with one or more tabs or newlines followed by a certain word and then ending with one or more tabs or newlines:

Here is an example:

```
c <- "beginning of string\tmiddle of string\t=\t\tDelete this section =\n\t\t-\tWhy does this disappear\t\nEnd of string"
```

When I run this:

```
gsub(paste0("[\n\t\r]+","delete",".*[\n\t\r]+"), "\n",c, ignore.case = TRUE, fixed = FALSE)
```

I end up with

```
"beginning of string\tmiddle of string\t=\nEnd of string"
```

But I want to be getting

```
"beginning of string\tmiddle of string\t=\n-\tWhy does this disappear\t\nEnd of string"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matches are "greedy" by default. Use a non-greedy quantifier

```
gsub(paste0("[\n\t\r]+?","delete",".*[\n\t\r]+"), "\n",c, ignore.case = TRUE, fixed = FALSE)
# [1] "beginning of string\tmiddle of string\t=\n\t\t-\tWhy does this disappear\t\nEnd of string"
```

[This intro](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) might help understand what's going on.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the extent of regex "greediness". Thank you both for the answer and the tutorial. Both very helpful!